# Proper way to convert string from Postgres back to a bytes in python

Tags: python, postgresql, byte, saltedhash

I have a postgresql db which contains following data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UaNX.png)
credentials are bytes stored in table with usage of psycopg2.Binary.

The issue is that the SELECT query run via Python returns strings (I need bytes to verify the credentials)

```
    def login_to_account(self):

        query = '''SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = %s'''
        try:
            result = db_ops.execute_queries(query, (self.username_input.text(),))
            is_correct_password(salt=result[2], pw_hash=result[3], password=self.password_input.text())
        except:
            QMessageBox.about(self, "Błąd logowania", "<b><p align='center'>Login lub hasło niepoprawne!<br>")
```

How can I convert it back? If this is a wrong way of storing and verifying credentials please let me know, Im new to this kind of stuff.

This is my salt+hash function that I use to encrypt and decrypt the data

```
import hmac

def hash_new_password(password: str) -> Tuple[bytes, bytes]:
    """
    Hash the provided password with a randomly-generated salt and return the
    salt and hash to store in the database.
    """
    salt = os.urandom(16)
    pw_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode(), salt, 100000)
    return salt, pw_hash

def is_correct_password(salt: bytes, pw_hash: bytes, password: str) -> bool:
    """
    Given a previously-stored salt and hash, and a password provided by a user
    trying to log in, check whether the password is correct.
    """
    return hmac.compare_digest(
        pw_hash,
        hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode(), salt, 100000)
    )
```

Comment: 1) **DO NOT use images for textual data** per [Don't use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Copy and paste as text. 2) `psycopg2.Binary` is meant to be used with Postgres `bytea` type per [Binary](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-binary)